# Partial itertools.product in python

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I would like to create the following list of tuples in Python, based on a list of possible values `[0, 1, 2, 3]`:

```py
(0, 0,  0),  # all set to first value: 0
(0, 0,  1),
(0, 0,  2),
(0, 0,  3),
(0, 1,  0),
(0, 2,  0),
(0, 3,  0),
(1, 0,  0),
(2, 0,  0),
(3, 0,  0),
(3, 3,  3),   # all set to last value: 3
```

To summarize:

- first value (`0`) for all elements of the tuples
- each value of the list of values (`[0, 1, 2, 3]`) for a given element of the tuple and other elements set to 0
- last value (`3`) for all elements of the tuples

What would be an efficient way to do it? ... maybe there is a magic function to do it?

I was first thinking of using `itertools.product` and then filtering:

```py
list(product([0, 1, 2, 3], repeat=3))
```

... or maybe by using `pandas` (which looks a bit overkill though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a super ugly way, that might need to be optimized (but at least it's working):

```py
[
 t for t in product(range(4), repeat=3)
 if all(e==0 for e in t) or all(e==3 for e in t) or sum([e!=0 for e in t])==1
]
```

**[EDIT]**

I found another way to build the list using `chain` and `product`:

```py
from itertools import chain, product

values = list(range(4))  # basically: [0, 1, 2, 3]
dflt = [values[0]] * 3  # basically: [0, 0, 0]
list(
    chain(
        [tuple([values[0]] * 3)],
        (tuple(dflt[:i] + [v] + dflt[i + 1 :]) for i, v in product(range(3), values[1:])),
        [tuple([values[-1]] * 3)],
    )
)
```

That gives the following result:

```py
[(0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (2, 0, 0),
 (3, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 2, 0),
 (0, 3, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 3),
 (3, 3, 3)]
```

Comment: You *can't* make an efficient solution with `product`; it will generate far too much and you'll always end up spending most of the work on filtering out the elements you don't want.

Comment: I guess you are right :) unless we use `product` to get the value and the position in the tuple where you store that value (inside an iterator or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

You can make this list comprehension

```py
for x in [ (a,b,c) 
    for a in range(4) 
    for b in range(4) 
    for c in range(4) 
    if a+b   == 0 
    or b+c   == 0 
    or a+c   == 0 
    or a+b+c == 9
]: print(x)
```

Comment: interesting. But actually as @ShadowRanger mentioned, using `product` (or worse, doing combined `for` loops), is not quite optimized.

Comment: If you check the implementation of product you'll see that it has about 5 for loops - and You will need many for loops to solve this problem - else you will not know if you get the right result . - The only way  to optimize the code is to use another language. - chain and product are implemented in C and therefore it is approximately double speed from my algorithm - but if you implement this case yourself in C you will get it even faster than product.

Comment: Indeed, an implementation in C would be the fastest... although actually I don't care much about speed here because I won't be creating many of these ;)  ... for reference: the implementation in C can be found here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l2307